# How to define axis labels for ggplots elsewhere in code?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As my variables are coded as p1, p2, p3 etc, I need to plot them using their actual meaningful names.

How to advance my code to do that? I tried something like this but did not work.

```
p1_title = "Smoking rate"
p2_title = "Traffic injury rate"

data %>% ggplot(aes(p1, outcomevariable))+
geom_line()+
xlab(p1_title)

data %>% ggplot(aes(p2, outcomevariable))+
geom_line()+
xlab(p2_title)
```

Comment: Please, add an example data, and the code for actual plot you want to make (e.g. add at least one layer to your plot, such as `geom_col`,  `geom_line` etc.).

Comment: Sorry as I forgot to add "geom_" line. Sorry, the code I provided started to work by itself. In my real example, I had too long text provided in p1_title and p2_title - i just needed to shorten them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the code, should be done it:
Source: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-axis-labels/#change-axis-labels

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = factor(dose), y = len)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

# Default plot
print(p)

# Change axis labels
p <- p + labs(x = "Dose (mg)", y = "Teeth length")
p
```

KR